# Find at least two rows coresponding to same id with different values

Tags: sql

Find those rows of same client which has at least one with state as 1 (non-deleted) and one with state as -1 (deleted) rows, here:

> state =  1 means non-deleted,
>
> state = -1 means deleted

```
row_id  client_id  client_name   state 
1       10000      ABC Ltd.       -1
2       10000      ABC Ltd.       -1
3       10000      ABC Ltd.        1
4       20000      ABCDE Ltd.     -1
5       20000      ABCDE Ltd.     -1
6       20000      ABCDE Ltd.      1
7       30000      ABCDEFG Ltd.    1
8       30000      ABCDEFG Ltd.   -1
9       40000      ABCdefghi Ltd.  1
10      50000      XYZ Ltd.        1
```

e.g., the output will be like:

```
row_id  client_id  client_name   state 
1       10000      ABC Ltd.       -1
2       10000      ABC Ltd.       -1
3       10000      ABC Ltd.        1
4       20000      ABCDE Ltd.     -1
5       20000      ABCDE Ltd.     -1
6       20000      ABCDE Ltd.      1
7       30000      ABCDEFG Ltd.    1
8       30000      ABCDEFG Ltd.   -1
```

here in this case client_id 40000 & 50000 are not displayed because they are having only one record with  state 1 and not having any record with the corresponding state as -1.

Comment: Ms sql server and mysql are two different products with different implementations of sql. I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.client_id = t.client_id and t1.state <> t.state
)
```

Since `-1`and `1` are the only possible values, you just need to ensure that another record exists with the same `client_id` and a different `state`.

Answer (score 0):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 
  exists (select 1 from tablename where client_id = t.client_id and state = -1)
  and
  exists (select 1 from tablename where client_id = t.client_id and state = 1)
```

or with a subquery that returns all the needed client_ids:

```
select * from tablename 
where client_id in (
  select client_id
  from tablename
  group by client_id
  having min(state) = -1 and max(state) = 1
)
```